# Mathematical treatment of mass action kinetics with detailed balance (as opposed to complex balance)

Tags: dynamical-systems, chemistry

I'm looking for a mathematical treatment of mass action kinetics under the assumption of detailed balance. In particular, I'm interested in the proof that the free energy is a global [Lyapunov function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function).

There are many papers that prove this for the more general case of "complex balance". However, I'm not particularly interested in that generalisation, because I'm interested in applications to chemistry, which means making different generalisations that are not compatible with it.

So my questions are:

1. What is a nice, simple proof that assumes detailed balance and shows that the free energy is a global Lyapunov function?
2. Is there a good overview paper that gives a concise mathematical treatment of the subject without making generalisations beyond what can be observed in a real (closed) chemical system?

Comment: Looking at this question years later, I'm not sure what I meant by "different generalisations that are not compatible with [an assumption of detailed balance]". Perhaps I had mixed up the notions of a *complex balanced stationary state* and *network with deficiency zero*. A deficiency zero network may only have complex-balanced stationary states, but there's nothing to stop networks with non-zero deficiency from having them as well. Every detailed balanced state is a complex balanced state, so there's no problem using results about complex balance to reason about 'real' networks in equilibrium

Comment: In any case, if someone has the same question as me then post a comment here and I'll post a more detailed explanation as an answer. Otherwise this question is probably fairly useless and can be ignored.